About foreign IRA reporting can you tell if I understood this right?
I live abroad as a US citizen in my native country . I still keep my native citizenship as well and here we can open IRA, with matching from government which is a pretty good deal. So far I didn't yet open such IRA account because I thought there would be millions of tons of info to report to USA about all companies' incomes balance sheets etc in the foreign IRA, which I didn't know how and I am not sure if anyone living on earth can. But now I was reviewing instructions for form 3520. Look at page 2 of 13 of the pdf file. On the left, at the upper side, it talks about certain eligible individuals, which is under exceptions to filing. And it gives a link to https://www.irs.gov/irb/2020-12_IRB#REV-PROC-2020-17. Here I couldn't understand everything but as far as I can tell, if it is a foreign tax favored retirement account, we are not required to report 3520. Am I right or I miss something here? If I am right, and we do not have to report the foreign IRA account in 3520, then does it mean there is also nowhere else to report this to US and does it mean I do not have to report it to US at all?

It would be very useful to people who answer your question if you state whether there is a tax treaty (or double taxation avoidance agreement (DTAA) in lieu of a tax treaty) between your country and the US.

There is a tax treaty yes.

You should probably talk to a local US-licensed tax advisor specializing in the US expats in your country.
Generally, the revenue procedure you linked to exempts pension schemes and other similar trusts from reporting. Whether it applies to your specific situation we cannot tell.
Keep in mind that this revenue procedure only exempts the reporting based on the IRC Sec. 6048, but not FBAR or FATCA related reporting. Similarly, while the pension fund reporting may be exempt, the income may not be. Tax treaties may augment that, but generally income exempt in your home country may not be exempt in the US.

There is no income yet. Similar to US IRA. You open the account, money is accummulated there. and you mean 6048 or 6038? So if I read 6048 and reach to the conclusion of no reporting then thats it? Or is there anywhere else to look at?

@upstream the money accumulates there means that there is income. For example, you said there's a government grant? There's a pre-tax contribution from your salary? As I said - it's hard to tell you if that is it given the lack of details. I suggest you talk to a tax advisor.

No there is not income. In the US when your money accummulates in your IRA, do you regard that as income? No. Similar thing. You only consider that as income when you take distribution. I will not take distributions yet. There is no government grant, I didnt say such thing., There is government matching of what you contirbute,. Just like in the US your company matches a percent of your contribution to your 401K for instance. You do not report that as income either do you?

@upstream You seem to not understand. I suggest, again, you talk to a licensed professional. In the US, IRA contribution may or may not be tax deductible. Company matches are under deferred taxation. These are specific and explicit code provisions that don't apply to foreign trusts.

I didn't ask question here to get told that I should talk to an accountant. I already know that alternative. I provided a link and asked if my thinking is right. If you don't know the answer it is fine. And no until you get distribution from an IRA or 401K, you do not have income from it in the US.

@upstream to clarify as to what your misunderstanding is: The 401k plan is a plan under the IRC Sec. 401(k). The IRA is a plan under the IRC Sec. 408. Go read the first paragraph in both of these sections. I'm sure if you put a bit more thinking to it you'll understand what I'm trying to tell you.

The answer to your question is no, I'm sorry it's not the answer you wanted to hear.
